# How do i know exactly what is taking up space in iCloud?

Tags: icloud

Got an email from Apple saying that my iCloud account is almost full. I'd like to know with what exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your iPhone/iPad, go to Settings->iCloud->Storage and Backup->Manage Storage.

On your Mac, go into System preferences ->iCloud and click on the button labeled "Manage…" to see an overview of the usage per app / service.